# Test Settings setup and cleanup scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file script from Microsoft Test Manager using Test Settings, but it gives an error.

```
TestOutcome 'Error'; Message 'The setup batch file exited with error code 1.'
```

My batch file:

```
setx SERVERTEST "TEST" -m
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `setx /?` shows some examples of using the command, one of them is `SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M`. This follows the Windows style that options start with a `/`. The code in your question ends with `-m`.

Try replacing the `-m` with `/m` or with `/M`.

Comment: You question suggested it always gave that error. Stating where the batch file worked and where it failed would have given us more information to better help you. What else have you tried but not described in the question?